# Interval (mathematics) $(a,b] , [a,b) , ( -\infty , +\infty ) $

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

now :
What are these? open or closed ?

$(a,b] , [a,b) , ( -\infty , +\infty ) $

Which set is open?

Which set is closed?

Comment: Neither, neither, both.

Comment: The last one is often called *[clopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set)* in English. This is an ugly term, but it's accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a,b]$ and $[a,b)$ are neither open, no closed (yes, not every set is necessary open or closed), it will be good if you prove it by yourself. $(-\infty,\infty)$ is the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$, so it is open and closed in the same time (another example of such set is $\{\emptyset\}$).

Answer (score 1):

They are called *half-open* intervals. Check here as well :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)